# How can I distinguish a global variable and a internal variable in C++?

Tags: c++, variables, namespaces, global-variables

I am trying to learn C++ and currently I am looking at the namespaces, I want to ask you how can I distinguish in my code the use of a global variable "a" and a internal variable "a" of my main function. I want to edit my second std::out to a form which will display the global value of "a". Is that possible ? Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

int a = 10;

namespace ns1
{
    int a = 20;
}

namespace ns2
{
    int a = 30;
}

//using namespace ns1;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int a = 40;

    {
        int a = 50;

        std::cout << a << std::endl; //a=50
    }

    std::cout << a << std::endl; //a=50
    std::cout << a << std::endl; //a = 10 ??? how can i do that by only editing this line ?
    std::cout << ns1::a << std::endl; //a= 20
    std::cout << ns2::a << std::endl; //a=30

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: You can use prefix `::` to indicate the global namespace.